# How can I not sending anything to controller if user not checked checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, radio-button, erb, nested-attributes

I have a form that have 2 kind of input radio button and checkbox.
I'm using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` to do a nested attribute
so, for the radio button it's work fine

```
<%= questions.each do |question| %> 
  <%= f.fields_for :user_response do |response| %>
   <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
    <%= response.radio_button :answer_id, answer.id %>
   <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end  %>
```

it's will sending the answer_id of the choice which user selected

but, on the checkbox

```
<%= questions.each do |question| %> 
 <% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :user_response do |response| %>
   <%= response.check_box :answer_id, {}, answer.id, nil %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
<% end  %>
```

it's have some problem ,when user isn't check the checkbox it still send data with nil values of answer_id because of 
`<%= response.check_box :answer_id, {}, answer.id, nil %>`

my question is how can i send only the answer_id of checked check box.

Comment: sorry for late reply, no it's still send a nil answer_id

Comment: The last argument of the `check_box` is a `unchecked_value`. Do you want to store it as `false`?

Comment: I want to don't send this response if user not check. right now it's send to create a nil answer_id response for unchecked choice.

Comment: Try this `<%= response.check_box :answer_id, {}, answer.id, false %>`

Comment: work like a charm !! thankyou so much you save my day :)

Comment: Great! I will be posting my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [***API Doc***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/check_box)

> check_box(object_name, method, options = {}, checked_value = "1",
>   unchecked_value = "0")

The last argument of the `check_box` is `unchecked_value`. It stores what value you given to that when the `check_box` isn't checked. You have `nil` as value so the values are stored as `nil`. Changing it to like below would solve your problem

```
<%= response.check_box :answer_id, {}, answer.id, false %>
```